# Concat created Nan values even after index_reset

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation, nan

I want to create a csv file that combines the train and test data and labels to use it for a project. The problem is that in concat function, even after using the index reset, the labels continue being Nan and i don't understand what is wrong. The datasets are in this link : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9f0562b7ec341ebb663262af78971b8020211228154538/84d58d

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
 
# remove first col from training dataset
data = pd.read_csv('/home/katerina/Desktop/PBMC_training_set_data.csv')
first_column = data.columns[0]  
data = data.drop([first_column], axis=1)
data.to_csv('new1.csv', index=False)

# remove first col from testing dataset
data2 = pd.read_csv('/home/katerina/Desktop/PBMC_testing_set_data.csv')
first_column = data2.columns[0]  
data2 = data2.drop([first_column], axis=1)
data2.to_csv('new2.csv', index=False)

#read training labels
data_labels = pd.read_csv('/home/katerina/Desktop/PBMC_training_set_label.csv')
#read testing labels
data2_labels = pd.read_csv('/home/katerina/Desktop/PBMC_testing_set_label.csv')

train = pd.concat([data_labels, data], axis=1, join='inner')
print(train.shape)
test = pd.concat([data2_labels, data2], axis=1, join='inner')
print(test.shape)
test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
train.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
frame = pd.concat([train, test], axis=0)
print(frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what's happening is you have duplicate index values before the `concat()`. (They're possibly only duplicated between the train & test sets, not necessarily duplicates within the sets separately.) That might throw off `concat()`, since index values are assumed to be unique... and it might compensate by setting some to NaN. The calls to `reset_index()` are going to give each of them separately index values starting from 1.

To fix this: Set ignore_index=True in pd.concat().  From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat):

> ignore_index: bool, default False If True, do not use the index values
> along the concatenation axis. The resulting axis will be labeled 0, …,
> n - 1. This is useful if you are concatenating objects where the
> concatenation axis does not have meaningful indexing information. Note
> the index values on the other axes are still respected in the join.

If that doesn't work, check: Do test & train have NaNs in the index before concatenation and after reset_index()? They shouldn't, but check.  If they do, those will carry over into the concat.

Comment: I tryed ignore_index = True but it didnt work either. I also checked that there are no Nan values in the original dataset. Nothing worked ... Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I just did concats with different order and it worked.
The nans were the result of no merging the labels right. Instead of creating one single col with labels I created two with half of them empty, one with the train_labels and one with test_labels.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
 
# remove first col from training dataset
data = pd.read_csv('/home/katerina/Desktop/PBMC_training_set_data.csv')
first_column = data.columns[0]  
data = data.drop([first_column], axis=1)
print(data.shape)

# remove first col from testing dataset
data2 = pd.read_csv('/home/katerina/Desktop/PBMC_testing_set_data.csv')
first_column = data2.columns[0]  
data2 = data2.drop([first_column], axis=1)
print(data2.shape)

#read training labels
data_labels = pd.read_csv('/home/katerina/Desktop/PBMC_training_set_label.csv')
print(data_labels.shape)
#read testing labels
data2_labels = pd.read_csv('/home/katerina/Desktop/PBMC_testing_set_label.csv')
print(data2_labels.shape)
#concat data without labels
frames = [data, data2]
d = pd.concat(frames)

#concat labels
l = data_labels.append(data2_labels)

#create the original dataset 
print(d.shape, l.shape)
dataset = pd.concat([l, d], axis=1)
dataset = shuffle(dataset)
dataset
```

Comment: Your train and test sets have different columns?  That seems like it'll create more problems later too